# How do I remove a "Burned" image on a DVD RW Drive?

Tags: windows-8.1, dvd-burning

I burned an ISO file to a DVD-RW disk in Windows 8.1 but would like to erase the disk. How do I do this?

Comment: Right click drive with the DVDRW disk in question and select 'erase disk'

Answer (score 2):

Most CD/DVD burning softwares will have an "Erase Disk" option somewhere in the menus.

If you are using the built-in Windows features, open the file explorer (press the Windows key + E), click on your DVD burner, and "Erase disc" should appear at the top menu if the disc in the drive is eraseable.

You can't erase normal DVD's or CD's, just ones with "RW" on the label.  If you have a non-RW disc just recycle the disc in a manner of your choosing.